# How to access multiple ip cameras from python

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, face-recognition

I have been trying to access my different IP cameras from python code, but it able to access the camera which is set on channel one, and that too when I am giving the IP address of my NVR so it directly access the Camera which is put on channel one.

I am sharing the code below which i am trying to run-

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://Username:password@Ipaddress') #IP address

while(True):
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imshow("RTSP",frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): #click q to stop capturing
break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried to access my different IP cameras which are connectd to my NVR,but i am unable to do it,i am able to access only the camera which is set in Channel 1 ,only when i pass the ip address of my nvr,when i try to give the ip of my cameras it shows error.

Can anyone have the answer of my query?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the provided RTSP URL is missing the path to the video stream. Typically, the path should include the specific stream and channel information for the camera. The URL should be in the following format:

```
rtsp://Username:password@Ipaddress/Streaming/Channels/ChannelNumber
```

Here's an updated version of your code with the correct RTSP URL format and fixed indentation:

```
import cv2

# Replace with your camera's credentials and channel number
username = 'your_username'
password = 'your_password'
ip_address = 'your_ip_address'
channel_number = 1

# Camera stream URL
stream_url = f'rtsp://{username}:{password}@{ip_address}/Streaming/Channels/{channel_number}'

# Open the camera stream
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    cv2.imshow("RTSP", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # Press 'q' to stop capturing
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I already tried this but is doing nothing

Comment: Masoom Raza,did u tried this code as it is not running on my end

Comment: Please provide the error statement.

Comment: It is not giving any error ,it successfully runs the code but I am not getting any response